# Expected number of slots

Tags: probability, expected-value

Let's say we have an expanding system of slots(you can be keep increasing the number of slots). Now I have a very large number of coins in a bag, all equi-similar, labeled(1,2,..n). Now the experiment is, you take a random coin from the bag and put it in a slot. Now you keep repeating this until you have at-least one coin of each label.

Variant: You keep repeating until you have the sequence(1,2,..n) in the slots, by sequence I mean the coins need not be adjacent.

What is the expected number of slots we would need?

Edit:

I didn't want to include this, but since MSE suggested my question didn't have enought context,

Basically my goal is to calculate the expected number of visits to some n states given that, as soon as all the states are visited in order 1,2...n(again this needs to appear only as a sequence in the visit order) the visits end.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: This sounds just like the coupon collector problem and its variants... have you at least read about the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) elsewhere?  Have you identified where (if at all) your question is different in any way, and can you communicate how (if at all) it is different?

Comment: @JMoravitz You are right, it answers the first part. Can you help me with the variant?

Comment: To be clear, your "variant" is that you have to first "find" a 1.  Then after having found a 1, you keep an eye out for a 2..  Only after having found a 2 (which itself is some time after the found 1) you keep an eye out for the 3, and then when looking for the 4 it only counts if after the 3 that was after the 2 that was after the 1... but with possible delay between.  The technique to finding the expected wait is the same.  At each step of the process, you will have a $\frac{1}{n}$ probability of hitting the next needed number in sequence for a wait time of $n$ at each step.

Comment: With $n$ steps needed, each with wait time of $n$, that makes it a total wait time of $n^2$

Comment: Yes you are right about the formulation of the variant.I can do the math to E[wait time] = n.( (1/n+((n-1)/n^2)*2+...) which is a arithmetic geometric progression) but I wonder how you arrived at that in a more simpler way. And are you saying that E[wait time for 1] = E[wait time for 2], but wait time for 2 depends on the occurance of 1 beforehand isn't it?Let's say 1 never occured, now the wait time for 2 is inf. Can you elaborate. Thanks.

Comment: @JMoravitz forgot to tag.

Comment: Letting $X$ be the total wait time... we have that $X=X_1+X_2+X_3+\dots+X_n$ where $X_i$ is the wait time to find $i$ that specifically occurs counting *from* having successfully found *and counted* the value $i-1$.  It is clear that $E[X]=E[X_1+X_2+\dots]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+\dots$ thanks to linearity.  "*Let's say 1 never occurred...*"  Impossible, it will occur eventually with 100% probability.  Again, if the sequence began 531333111623115....  that would have been $X_1=3$ since $1$ was the third number of 531333111623115.  Then $X_2=8$ since $2$ was the eighth number of 33311162.

Comment: @JMoravitz: (I'm sure you know this and just weren’t using the term in its technical sense; just to make sure others don’t misunderstand): That $1$ never occurs isn’t impossible; it merely has probability $0$; that is, it [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) will not occur. The expected value of a random variable can be finite even if it’s possible that its value is infinite, as long as the probability for that to occur is $0$.